# CSV on heroku Cedar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I want to use the CSV module with rails 3.2.1 on heroku cedar, but

```
require 'CSV'
```

doesn't works

here is the error when testing with the console:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.1)
irb(main):001:0> require 'CSV'
LoadError: no such file to load -- CSV
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you add it to your bundle and ran bundle install?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try

```
require 'csv'
```

it's case sensitive.

UPDATE: This isn't a Heroku problem mind you - if you did the same locally you'd get the same eror. CSV is in the standard library in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: simple enough, thanks, it works in upper case and lower on my local machine, any idea why?

Comment: locally I use ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]

Comment: indeed it does, same as on ruby 1.9.2p290 (also on OSX) - my bad.

Comment: Case insensitive filesystems such as the ones commonly used in windows and OSX (although HFS+ can be configured to be case-sensitive) let you do things that will blow up in a case sensitive environment. Your production system is linux, most likely.